# Scene is not Loading

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There are 9 scenes in total. All are Added in "Build Settings". 7 scenes out of 9 are loading, but when I try to load other 2 scenes it kept saying:

> Scene 'SceneName' couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to the build settings or the AssetBundle has not been loaded. To add a scene to the build settings use the menu File->Build Settings... UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager:LoadSceneAsync(String, LoadSceneMode) MoreMountains.CorgiEngine.c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/CorgiEngine/Common/Scripts/Managers/LoadingSceneManager.cs:88) UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator) MoreMountains.CorgiEngine.LoadingSceneManager:Start() (at Assets/CorgiEngine/Common/Scripts/Managers/LoadingSceneManager.cs:67)

[image: Here is my "Scene In Build" Image]

I have already added the scene in the scene manager but it keeps showing this error. I have tried so much. Please help me to sort out the problem. Here is my "LoadingSceneManager" script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MoreMountains.Tools;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

namespace MoreMountains.CorgiEngine
{   
public class LoadingSceneManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [Header("Binding")]
    /// The name of the scene to load while the actual target scene is 
    loading (usually a loading screen)
    public static string LoadingScreenSceneName="LoadingScreen";

    [Header("GameObjects")]
    /// the text object where you want the loading message to be displayed
    public Text LoadingText;
    /// the canvas group containing the progress bar
    public CanvasGroup LoadingProgressBar;
    /// the canvas group containing the animation
    public CanvasGroup LoadingAnimation;
    /// the canvas group containing the animation to play when loading is complete
    public CanvasGroup LoadingCompleteAnimation;

    [Header("Time")]
    /// the duration (in seconds) of the initial fade in
    public float StartFadeDuration=0.2f;
    /// the speed of the progress bar
    public float ProgressBarSpeed=2f;
    /// the duration (in seconds) of the load complete fade out
    public float ExitFadeDuration=0.2f;
    /// the delay (in seconds) before leaving the scene when complete
    public float LoadCompleteDelay=0.5f;

    protected AsyncOperation _asyncOperation;
    protected static string _sceneToLoad = "";
    protected float _fadeDuration = 0.5f;
    protected float _fillTarget=0f;
    protected string _loadingTextValue;

    /// <summary>
    /// Call this static method to load a scene from anywhere
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sceneToLoad">Level name.</param>
    public static void LoadScene(string sceneToLoad) 
    {       
        _sceneToLoad = sceneToLoad;                 
        Application.backgroundLoadingPriority = ThreadPriority.High;
        if (LoadingScreenSceneName!=null)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(LoadingScreenSceneName);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// On Start(), we start loading the new level asynchronously
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void Start() 
    {
        _loadingTextValue=LoadingText.text;
        if (_sceneToLoad != "")
        {
            StartCoroutine(LoadAsynchronously());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Every frame, we fill the bar smoothly according to loading progress
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void Update()
    {
        LoadingProgressBar.GetComponent<Image>().fillAmount = MMMaths.Approach(LoadingProgressBar.GetComponent<Image>().fillAmount,_fillTarget,Time.deltaTime*ProgressBarSpeed);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the scene to load asynchronously.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual IEnumerator LoadAsynchronously() 
    {
        // we setup our various visual elements
        LoadingSetup();

        // we start loading the scene
        _asyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(_sceneToLoad,LoadSceneMode.Single );
        _asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = false;

        // while the scene loads, we assign its progress to a target that we'll use to fill the progress bar smoothly
        while (_asyncOperation.progress < 0.9f) 
        {
            _fillTarget = _asyncOperation.progress;
            yield return null;
        }
        // when the load is close to the end (it'll never reach it), we set it to 100%
        _fillTarget = 1f;

        // we wait for the bar to be visually filled to continue
        while (LoadingProgressBar.GetComponent<Image>().fillAmount != _fillTarget)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        // the load is now complete, we replace the bar with the complete animation
        LoadingComplete();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(LoadCompleteDelay);

        // we fade to black
        GUIManager.Instance.FaderOn(true,ExitFadeDuration);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(ExitFadeDuration);

        // we switch to the new scene
        _asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets up all visual elements, fades from black at the start
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void LoadingSetup() 
    {
        GUIManager.Instance.Fader.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        GUIManager.Instance.Fader.GetComponent<Image>().color=new Color(0,0,0,1f);
        GUIManager.Instance.FaderOn(false,ExitFadeDuration);

        LoadingCompleteAnimation.alpha=0;
        LoadingProgressBar.GetComponent<Image>().fillAmount = 0f;
        LoadingText.text = _loadingTextValue;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when the actual loading is done, replaces the progress bar with the complete animation
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void LoadingComplete() 
    {
        LoadingCompleteAnimation.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine(MMFade.FadeCanvasGroup(LoadingProgressBar,0.1f,0f));
        StartCoroutine(MMFade.FadeCanvasGroup(LoadingAnimation,0.1f,0f));
        StartCoroutine(MMFade.FadeCanvasGroup(LoadingCompleteAnimation,0.1f,1f));

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "I have already added the scene in scene manager"? Are you talking about the Build Settings? (Menu `File` > `Build Settings`). Are you sure the name of the scene you are trying to load is **exactly** the name of the scene in the Build Settings?

Comment: Just a side note on style, you don't need to prefix your private/protected variables with underscores in C#. You can use `this.sceneToLoad = sceneToLoad` rather than the underscore syntax.

Comment: @Hellium yes i am talking about the build settings, all the scenes i want to be loaded are in build settings with correct name, but still it shows the error

Comment: @Hellium yes it is also checked. i have updated the question, also added the Build setting Screenshot link. please do check it

Comment: @Hellium out of nine Scenes it only opens 7 scenes, when trying to open "Level1" and "Level4" it shows the error.

Answer (score 4):

Have you added your scene which you try to load into the build settings "Scenes In Build" Section?
This is required to switch to any scene inside your project using the scenemanager.

[image]

Comment: yes i have already added all the scenes in "Scene In Build " with correct name

Answer (score 1):

or you can use by their index values its much easier approach rather then using string

SceneManager.LoadScene(0);

and then add all those scene by opening build setting window

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but my answer might be still valuable to some people having this problem. The scenes you add to your build should avoid more exotic characters like german umlauts "äöÜß" or simmilar. And it'll be better if you avoid whitespace characters as well - as they might contain some other sign then you suspect and therefore cause trouble. Especially when you did a copy&paste to name them. So better stick to plain ASCII letters and replace all blanks with hyphen or underscore.

Answer (score 0):

GO File-> and Build Setting make sure you have all the Scene in the box.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's look like You try to load scene with name: 'SceneName'.

1. Check if You have proper values on functions parameters.
2. Try to load problematic scenes using indexes instead of names.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your function "LoadScene".

I'm not sure what exact problem is but from your logs the problem is in "LoadScene" function.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I had all the scenes added in Build Settings properly, but it was still throwing an error when running the game in the editor (no problem when built for android).

I just removed all scenes from the Build Settings and added them back again. No problem at all after that.